# Group Join Select With Comma Separated

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, entity-framework-core

I have a query Like below in .net Core 2.2 with EF.

```
var data = context.Customer
                    .GroupJoin(context.Orders, c=> c.Id, o => o.CustoerId, (c, o) => new
                    {
                        customer = c,
                        orders= o
                    }).Select(s => new
                    {
                        s.customer.Name,
                        s.customer.Id,
                        AllOrdersRef = s.orders == null ? null : string.Join(", ", s.orders.Select(x => x.UniquRef))
                    });
```

It gives Error

> The LINQ expression 'Count()' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.

All I want is Comma Separated Value in AllOrdersRef. Also I dont want to use
ToList().

Comment: Are you sure this is where you get the error? There is no `.Count` here

Comment: I think `string.Join` will not be use in `IQuerable<T>` where you use linq on `DbSet<Customer>` and `DbSet<Orders>` so that why. might be you got some othe exception also

Comment: I believe you getting error on the right after of "c.customer.Id" because you dont have comma.

Comment: Why on earth would you want to string join UniqueRefs into a single string?

Answer (score 0):

You should make `join` query and then process it's result on *client* side:

```
var data = (from c in context.Customer
            join o in context.Orders on c.Id equals o.CustomerId into subs
            from sub in subs.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new 
            {
                 c.Id,
                 c.Name,
                 UniquRef = sub == null ? null : sub.UniquRef
            }).ToList();

var result = data.GroupBy(x => new { x.Id, x.Name }).Select(x => new 
             {
                 x.Key.Id,
                 x.Key.Name, 
                 AllOrdersRef = (x.Count() == 1 && x.First().UniquRef == null) ? null
                                    : String.Join(", ", x.Select(y => y.UniquRef))
             });
```

Comment: I think OP doesn't want `.ToList()` where he/she expect query return `IQuerable<T>`.

Comment: @er-sho, `String.Join` can't be translated to SQL, so `IQuerable<T>` also can't be achived, only `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: @SlavaUtesinov, there I performed join. But the Problem is I don't want it to evaluated locally by using ToList(). By the way thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding Sql Server (if it's your DBMS), there are two main functions that do the `string` concatenation on `group by` output, [XML Path and String_Agg (from Sql Server 2017)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273238/how-to-use-group-by-to-concatenate-strings-in-sql-server) none of which is supported in `linq to sql`. To the best of my knowledge, it is not supported for other DBMSes either, so the only way you have is to cast it to `Enumerable` before `string.Join`.
For this, you just need to call `ToList()` before `Select`:

```
var data = context.Customer
                    .GroupJoin(context.Orders, c=> c.Id, o => o.CustoerId, (c, o) => new
                    {
                        customer = c,
                        orders= o
                    })
                    .ToList()
                    .Select(s => new
                    {
                        s.customer.Name,
                        s.customer.Id
                        AllOrdersRef = s.orders == null ? null : string.Join(", ", s.orders.Select(x => x.UniquRef))
                    });
```